# Convert utf8 to 1251

Tags: c#, .net

Okay so the problem is as follows. I have to get the information from an online form and then submit it again(changed). The page is in "windows-1251" and in my request I get it with:

```
{
         // used to build entire input
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // used on each read operation
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        // prepare the web page we will be asking for
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(url);

        // execute the request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();

        // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            // fill the buffer with data
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            // make sure we read some data
            if (count != 0)
            {
                // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                tempString = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(buf, 0, count);

                // continue building the string
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

        // print out page source
        // Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
```

So after that I strip the page and get my data into an array and I need to post it to the site again but it needs to be encoded. I use System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode to do the encoding but I get a completely different results from my script and from firefox(I got the original using tamper data). So any help or ideas are appreciated. BTW after I got the encoded data (from the script) I tried it online at http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ and only UTF-8 returned the proper result. So I'm guessing I have to convert it to 1251 and I tried doing that but it was still gibberish and completely different that what it was supposed to be... So please if you can help me it will be great... :)

Edit:

```
Expected: %E3%F0%E0%E4+%D1%EE%F4%E8%FF
Actual: %D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4+%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F
f2[11] = град София
-       f2  {string[180]}   string[]
    [0] "127.0.0.1" string
    [1] "1348247257"    string
    [2] "1n132135075318435" string
    [3] "151669n1"  string
    [4] "0" string
    [5] null    string
    [6] null    string
    [7] null    string
    [8] "2" string
    [9] "12871449760521116" string
    [10]    "14"    string
    [11]    "град София"    string
    [12]    "Враждебна" string
    [13]    "42.707984,23.41341,0~бул. Ботевградско шосе"   string
    [14]    "42.7100653,23.4274006,1"   string
```

Comment: It's impossible to losslessly convert UTF-8 to 1251 because there are only ~251 possible characters for 1251 but many more for UTF-8. If you don't care about coming up with some possibly invalid strings, just treat the UTF-8 as 1252.

Comment: Everything is in Cyrillic so 1251 will actually do fine. If I'm not terribly wrong about something. :D

Comment: So, `tempString` is valid string. Then you extract data from the string, and covert it to an array. Then you encode that array with `UrlEncode`. And the problem is that result of `UrlEncode` is not the expected one? Could you please edit the question, and add an example of the string, the array, the result of UrlEncode that you get, and the result that you are expecting? Four items in total.

Comment: Out of curiosity was does response.ContentEncoding return?

Comment: Basically I get all the information from the <input> tags from the form and put them in an array. The array is just fine, I get it outputted on the Console and it prints out fine. But as far I as can see I can't see any problem on why this shouldn't be working...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is an array between "град София", and URL encoded string, the second item that I asked. What is it?

Comment: @Blam   ContentEncoding "" string
So I guess it is empty... Hmmm.

Comment: @Dialecticus I don't know if this is the right way to post the array but this is my first question on the website. (Btw I trilled by the fast responses on my question.)

Comment: Ah, that sort of array. I thought it was something else. Instead of `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` try [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx). It has additional encoding parameter. Encoding 1251 should go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (reached via comments) was to replace [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx) with [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode‌​`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx). This method has an overload that takes encoding as a parameter.